# Drop you off to your work

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition when you say:

> Sometimes, people need a personal driver to drop them off **at/to** their work

Is it **to** coz' it makes more sense to me as your are going to work, BUT the **at** maybe too... emphasizing specificity.

Comment: We "go **to** work" but we "get dropped off **at** work."

Comment: I agree with Robusto. But, as an aside, [this related question on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23789/3559) shows that "drop you off to your work" is acceptable in some dialects.

Comment: @MattEllen: what dialect, do you use that in your country?

Comment: It's the South Devon dialect in the UK. I think they also say it in Cornwall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, *to* is used to imply direction, or intention.

> They rode their horses **to** the old creek.
>
> I plan **to** be there by nine.
>
> Set the dial **to** eight and then check the meter.

*At* is used to imply location, moment in time, or position.

> They tied the horses **at** the side of the creek and went for a swim.
>
> I actually got there **at** nine-thirty.
>
> OK, the dial is **at** eight. What does the meter read?

Using this as a guide, it should make sense that you drive *to* work, and drop someone off *at* work:

> Sometimes, people need a personal chauffeur to **drive** them **to** work.
>
> Sometimes, people need a personal chauffeur to **drop** them **off at** work.

Comment: Thx. But why do you have to change my 'personal driver' to 'personal chauffeur'? Did I write it wrong?

Comment: @JohnArvin  Either is fine.  I just didn't want to repeat "drive".  You could write *"Sometimes people need a personal driver to **take** them to work"*.